# How to properly use InOut ObjectParameter in EF4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I recently had cause to bring back just a single value in addition to tabular data returned by my stored procedure.  Since EF doesn't support stored procedures with multiple result sets, I figured I could accomplish this via an output parameter.  However, using this method I encountered an issue where in I was getting only rounded values back for some numeric value fields.

The parameter to my stored procedure was declared as:

```sql
@MyValue    numeric(19,6) output
```

When calling the mapping function, I had:

```cs
var myValue = new ObjectParameter("MyValue", typeof(decimal));
List<MyResultItem> results = this.ObjectContext.CallMyStoredProc(someId, myValue).ToList();
```

This is what always returned the value rounded to an integer (i.e., scale zero).

I was first able to fix this by manually editing the underlying XML to the .edmx by manually adding Precision and Scale attributes:

```xml
<Parameter Name="MyValue" Type="numeric" Mode="InOut" Precision="19" Scale="6" />
```

This was, not surprisingly, completely discarded the next time I performed "Update Model from Database.."

I seem to have fixed it more reliably by updating my declaration for the `ObjectParameter` as such:

```cs
var myValue = new ObjectParameter("MyValue", 999999999.999999M);
```

However, this seems an awful lot like a hack, and I'm worried about issues in the future (even if it's just maintenance regarding this magic number).  Is there a better, and reliable, way to use output parameters within Entity Framework?

Comment: Decimals in .NET keep their digits so have you tried using 0.0M or 0.000000M instead to see if that works? That would at least be a bit less "magic", I'm guessing it's falling back to the default 0M (without digits)

Comment: @XIU No idea why it does this, but if I pass 0..M with any number of trailing zeros, then the resulting `myValue.Value` is always 0.  Additionally, the later ObjectParameters I send into the query are DBNull instead of getting set.  Absolutely bizarre.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166992/decimal-output-parameter-rounded-to-integer-in-ef5-0

Comment: @LSU.Net Hadn't found that in my initial search.  It is similar, but I had already discovered the workarounds provided there.  My question (maybe should have been on Programmer's StackExchange) was what would be the "correct" (reliable, maintainable, etc) solution.

Comment: In my quick research I don't believe there /is/ one. :)

Comment: @LSU.Net So looks like we're in the same boat.  Your linked question does at least let me know it's an issue others have faced, and that it's apparently still an issue still up to EF6.  Guess that ultimately, this "magic number" just has to be kept in sync with the database, which may be the correct solution, since in the Database First model of EF, you're already relying to a degree on keeping code + DB in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing this in more places, now, so I created a helper method for it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the maximum allowed value for a SQL numeric of the specified scale and precision.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scale">The scale.</param>
/// <param name="precision">The precision.</param>
/// <returns>Decimal representing the maximum value for the specified numeric.</returns>
public static decimal SqlNumericMax(int scale, int precision)
{
    return (decimal)Math.Pow(10, (scale - precision)) - (decimal)Math.Pow(10, (-1 * precision));
}
```

This doesn't absolve the use of magic numbers in code, but at least it does help provide an exact match between what you see in code to what you see in the database.  (i.e., for a `numeric(19,6)` stored proc parameter, you'll call `Utility.SqlNumericMax(19, 6)`, so the relationship is more immediately apparent.)

It looks like providing the maximum value to the parameter prior to the stored proc call is still the best and most reliable method for the call to populate the result correctly.