# Entity Framework 6 stored procedure call resultset decimal value is 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is an ASP.NET MVC project using EF6. A stored procedure needs to be called that takes a table-valued parameter. `EntityFrameworkExtras` is used to facilitate the call.

The stored procedure returns a result set with several rows and columns.  One of the columns is a `Decimal(8,2)`. The stored procedure is executed by calling EF6's

```
context.ExecuteStoredProcedure<ClassMatchingResultset>
```

The call is successful. A `List<ClassMatchingResultset>` is returned.  All the properties in it are filled out except for the decimal column which is zero on all rows.

The stored procedure tests out fine in SSMS, and returns the decimal values when calling it with the same parameters.

`ClassMatchingResultset` uses the `Decimal` datatype for the decimal property. The stored procedure is returning a select statement on a temp table with a decimal column of the same name.

What is happening here? The decimal property's name is `TotalCost`. Is `TotalCost` just not getting set at all? Is EF setting `TotalCost` to zero because of some problem reading the result set?

Comment: hello, can you show us the code ?

Comment: Could you be running into this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166992/decimal-output-parameter-rounded-to-integer-in-ef5-0

Comment: It does not appear to be an issue of rounding during type conversion.  I did try your suggestion of hard coding a number into the proc's resultset.  That worked!  If I put in 21, EF read that as an int, and threw a type conversion error.  If I put in 21.1, it was successful.  I tried casting the actual result from the proc to varchar, i.e.`cast(21.1 as varchar(10)) as TotalCost`  Can you believe that EF converted that to "0.00"?

Comment: I authored Crystal Reports years ago.  It would have trouble interpreting the results of some procs.  We discovered it was reading through the entire proc to interpret the resultset.  So I tried inserting the results into a new cte, and then a new temp table, then returning the results from that.  No dice.  It's time to write up a test project.  I'll share code when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to have nothing to do with EF6 or EF6 Extras.  The reason the proc worked fine when being called from SSMS was because the TVP was constructed correctly there.  The C# code however filled the TVP with incorrect values resulting in the proc returning zero for the decimal column.  Ugh!

The troubleshooting technique of repeatedly simplifying the .net code and the proc, and retesting after each iteration, eventually pinpointed the problem, but it took forever.

Test driven development would have uncovered this immediately and saved a tremendous amount of time.  In my experience, for TDD to by truly effective, it must be in a project using IoC containers and a mock framework. Those projects seem hard to come by.

Use of SQL Extended Events to trace the calls may have shown the value being passed into the proc's parameters.  This information is not available with EF6's built in logging feature.

Comment: You can always turn on tracing in EF to see which queries are being generated and use SQL Profiler to see what parameters are being sent to SQL Server

Comment: The EF tracing does not show the values of the parameters being passed to the stored procedure.  Profiler does not work with Azure.  It is being deprecated and replaced with Extended Events.